# Cannot get slices of interfaces to work

Tags: go

What I'm trying to do is to create a slice of an `interface` type and populating it with some struct types that are implementing this interface.

```
chans := []chan Event {
    make(chan FileEvent),
    make(chan NetworkEvent),
}
```

But this fails with `cannot use make(chan FileEvent) (type chan FileEvent) as type chan Event in array or slice literal`.

Now I am aware that this is [meant to be that way](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice).
However the suggested solution is a) not practical because I have a bunch of different types and cannot easily iterate over them and b) I cannot even get it to work, it still gives me the same error. I tried:

```
chans := make([]chan Event, 2)
chans[0] = make(chan FileEvent)
```

Do you guys know what I'm doing wrong or how this can be solved elegantly? Thanks a lot !!

Here are the definitions of the types:

```
type Event interface {
  GetId() string
}

type FileEvent struct {
}

func (e FileEvent) GetId() string {
  return "FileEvent"
}
```

Comment: Please include your definition for `Event`.

Comment: `chan Event` and `chan FileEvent` are different types. You can’t assign one to the other, as discussed in the linked document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Event` may be an interface type, but `chan Event` is not; it is a specific channel type. A `[]chan Event` is a slice, in which every element must be of type `chan Event`. However, a `chan Event` could accept messages of any type implementing `Event`.

Why? Consider this code:

```
chans := []chan Event {
    make(chan FileEvent),
    make(chan NetworkEvent),
}

ch := chans[0] // ch is of type chan Event because that's the type of elements of chans
ch <- NetworkEvent{} // Uh oh - we just tried to send a NetworkEvent to what's actually a chan FileEvent!
```

The send would be compile-time legal if your code were legal, but would cause a runtime type error, which is not allowed in Go as it uses strict static typing.

You could, however, make them all `chan Event`, and then you could send whatever types you needed, and use type assertions when receiving from those channels.